# Passing confirm dialog result to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var x = confirm("Ok or Cancel?");
alert(x);
```

In the example above, after clicking Ok or Cancel the returning value will be passed to 'x'. After receiving the value the alert(x) will be executed next;

My question is how does confirm passed it's value to 'x'? Apparently, the confirm box will wait for the user to click either OK or Cancel before executing alert(x).

Comment: `confirm` is a blocking function, it will stop code execution until you respond to the prompt. Then it returns a value, same as every other function that returns a value, which can then be stored into a variable.

Comment: `confirm` **pauses** the whole thread, and returns a value after you clicked `ok` or `cancel`.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, calling `confirm()` is a blocking operation.

As stated at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm):

> Dialog boxes are modal windows - **they prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed**. For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a dialog box (or modal window). And regardless, there are very good reasons to avoid using dialog boxes for confirmation.

Comment: This is what I'm aiming for: **they prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed**.

Is it possible to create a modal function in javascript?

Comment: absolutely, google for `modalbox javascript` and you will find tons of them

Comment: I find tons of them unfortunately they only block the program interface. I want to know too how to block the thread from execution.

Anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`confirm` is a function that takes an argument and returns a boolean.

So a simpler function that works similarly:

```
function trueIfMessage(message)
{
    return (message != '' && message != null);
}
```

That is a function that takes an argument and returns a boolean.

`confirm` has added greater functionality in that it shows the user a window and allows the user to make a choice. This side effect blocks the main thread until the user closes the window.

Comment: Actually I want to imitate the blocking of confirm dialog. In your given answer that won't block the next code.

Comment: It blocks the execution just the same as confirm does. All functions block, unless otherwise stated. The difference is that confirm waits for user input, as I state at the end of my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry. Your right. What I need is wait for user input before executing the next code. 

As of now, I'm using callback.